# Using sendkeys for symbols

Tags: vb.net

Using VB by the way.

When I click a button, I input a symbol % ^ ( ). When I tick it (CheckedListBox1) and press Start (Button1) for it to spam the symbols on notepad, it doesn't do it. I'm guessing it needs to be converted or a code needs to be declared to recognize that the symbol is being pressed. Basically, what I want is whatever I put IN, is the same as OUT.

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        On Error Resume Next

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then 'Only Checked Items of the CheckedListbox

        If IntCount > CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1 Then 'If the index is higher then the max. index of the checkedlistbox
            IntCount = 0 ' The index will reset to 0
        End If
        SendKeys.SendWait(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(IntCount).ToString & "{ENTER}") 'Send keys to the active windows
        IntCount += 1 'Goto the next line

    Else 'All items

        If IntCount > CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then 'If the index is higher then the max. index of the checkedlistbox
            IntCount = 0 ' The index will reset to 0
        End If
        SendKeys.SendWait(CheckedListBox1.Items(IntCount).ToString & "{ENTER}") 'Send keys to the active windows
        IntCount += 1 'Goto the next line

    End If
```

Comment: Special Characters like % ^ need curly braces surrounding them for `SendKeys.Send` to send them literally because they have another meaning otherwise (% ALT key, ^ CTRL key) so {%} should work

Comment: there is no code inside the sub..

Answer (score 0):

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to
>   specify the plus sign, use "{+}".

Source [MSDN SendKeys.Send Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)

Comment: You can see a fuller list of where the { } are needed at http://www.aformfiller.com/helpv310.html#change  All should work except the {!} for a 1/4 second pause which is a special command for the program described at the website link

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you want to just send the keys to the notepad, if the syntax for the SendKeys were right, the following tip should send your keys using SendKeys..

Activate the notepad window first.. by adding the code below to the Button:

```
AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad")
```

after that, send your keys..

then the code should send them to the notepad..

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't what I'm looking for. I'm trying to find a way to get the program to recognize that in the textbox, I have put a symbol "%", and that when I hit "Start" to play it back, it would display "%", and not just skip it. This and a couple other symbols are like this, but when it comes to numbers and letters, it's fine. For example, If I wanted to say "An increase of 100%", type it in and hit "Start", it would display "An increase of 100". See what I mean?